Flask Session Data Not Persisting Between Requests After Receiving from Spring Server
I am a beginner developer studying Flask for a week. I was building a chatbot using the OpenAI API, and my mentor advised me to minimize global variables. I switched to using sessions instead of global variables, but now I’m having issues with session data being None.
After receiving cust_id and prod_id from a Spring server and storing them in the session, the data is correctly printed after storing, but when I try to access it in the chatbot() function, both cust_id and prod_id show up as None.
Here’s a simplified version of my code:
from flask import Flask, session, request, jsonify, render_template
from openai import OpenAI
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)

api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')
client = OpenAI(api_key=api_key)

@app.route('/receive-cust-id', methods=['POST'])
def receive_cust_id():
    session['cust_id'] = request.json.get('custId')
    print("Session cust id : ", session['cust_id'])
    return jsonify({"status": "success"})

@app.route('/receive-prod-id', methods=['POST'])
def receive_prod_id():
    session['prod_id'] = request.json.get('prodId')
    print("Session prod id : ", session['prod_id'])
    return jsonify({"status": "success"})

@app.route('/chatbot', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def chatbot():
    print('Cust ID:', session.get('cust_id'))
    print('Prod ID:', session.get('prod_id'))
    return "Chatbot Page"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

However, the session values print as None in the chatbot() route, even though they are set correctly in the receive-cust-id and receive-prod-id routes. Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can retain the session data across requests?

===

Session cust id :  IMSI

127.0.0.1 - - \[07/Sep/2024 16:31:20\] "POST /receive-cust-id HTTP/1.1" 200 -

session :  \<SecureCookieSession {}\>

session.get(cust_id) :  None

session.get(prod_id) :  None

127.0.0.1 - - \[07/Sep/2024 16:31:20\] "GET /chatbot HTTP/1.1" 200 -

127.0.0.1 - - \[07/Sep/2024 16:31:20\] "GET /static/css/chatbot.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -

session :  \<SecureCookieSession {}\>

session.get(cust_id) :  None

session.get(prod_id) :  None

\[{'role': 'user', 'content': '만화책 한 권 추천해줘'}\]

127.0.0.1 - - \[07/Sep/2024 16:31:28\] "POST /chatbot HTTP/1.1" 200 -

prodId from spring: prod43

Session prod id :  prod43

127.0.0.1 - - \[07/Sep/2024 16:32:03\] "POST /receive-prod-id HTTP/1.1" 200 -

session :  \<SecureCookieSession {}\>

session.get(cust_id) :  None

session.get(prod_id) :  None

===

P.S. I have ensured that all browser cookie settings are set to “allow.”

It seems like the data in the session is being lost in between requests. Usually, the reason for this is the session cookie not being sent back by the client between requests, which makes the cookie unavailable. Try explicitly setting SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE and SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE if the cookie isn't being shared across requests
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE'] = True
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY'] = True
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE'] = 'Lax'  # Or 'None' for cross-domain requests

Also, I recommend using CORS (Cross-Origin Requests) because it allows the session cookie to be shared across domains.

Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is a mechanism for integrating applications. CORS defines a way for client web applications that are loaded in one domain to interact with resources in a different domain.

from flask_cors import CORS
CORS(app, supports_credentials=True)

Please do let me know if this works. Good luck!
